# Upgrading Process of Sonatype Nexus 2.14 to Nexus 3.41

Tags: repository, nexus, repo, sonatype, nexus3

I am trying to upgrade Sonatype Nexus 2.14 to latest 3.41.
Current Directory Structure /opt/nexus2/nexus2.14, sonatype-work.
My question is if i want to extract the latest version 3.41 should i do it in /opt/nexus2 ( its will then not create new sonatype-work as its already there) or should i make a new directory for it.

- If not then it will look like this /opt/nexus2/nexus2.14, nexsu3.41, sonatype-work,
- If yes then it will look like this /op/nexus2/nexus2.14 sonatype-work  &
  /opt/nexus3/nexus3.41 sonatype-work
  ..
  after installing nexus3.41 i will migrate all the work form nexus 2 to nexus 3 using GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn’t an “upgrade”, it is a migration. See here:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Upgrade+Procedures

The procedure outlined in that help document will import all the configuration and data from Nexus Repo 2 into a new Nexus Repo 3 instance. When finished, your original Nexus Repo 2 will still be intact, and you’ll have a new Nexus Repo 3 instance. Nexus Repo 2 and 3 should not be sharing the same work directory, make a new install location for the Nexus Repo 3 install and its work directory.